# Why "Unsubscribe" link from email uses GET method rather than POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE?

Tags: http, email, http-method

Just out of curiosity, I checked "Unsubscribe" links from commercial mails. I only checked 3 mails as a sample, but all of them were using GET method. It seems unintuitive to me since the function is not safe, so I thought either POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE method would be a better alternative.

Why "Unsubscribe" link from email uses GET method rather than POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE?

Comment: A mere URL is likely to work in any email client.

Comment: @e2-e4 Does this mean some clients can only support GET method?

Comment: An native hypertext/anchor-link *only* supports making a GET request. The other verbs are thus *not applicable* to the initial unsubscribe link request.

Comment: @user2864740 Does this mean most email clients only support hypertext/anchor-link? Sorry if this is a silly question, but I don't know about this.

Comment: I think another way to consider it: how would an email client initiate a POST request?